# C execution problem in sublime text program

Tags: c, sublimetext4

I have written this program on sublime text but when i run the program it doesn't give me option for input

I was expecting the software will ask for input
I wanted the program to ask for numbers so that i can get their total sum

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text is just an editor. You should install a compiler (e.g `gcc`) on your system and compile your code by running this command in a shell terminal window:

```bash
> gcc -o main main.c
```

In Windows, this will generate an `main.exe` file. Then you can run this executable file by running this command at the shell prompt:

```bash
> .\main
```

Or if you are running on a Unix system:

```bash
> ./main
```

Now your program is running and is listening for user input.